# Composer.json with Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to install a module into Zend Framework 2 via composer.json but I am running into syntax errors

Here is the actual code itself:

`{

      "name" : "zendframework/skeleton-application",

      "description" : "Skeleton Application for ZF2",

      "require" : { 

      "php" : ">=5.4", 

      "zendframework/zendframework" : ">2.2.0rc1", 
 
    },

  "keywords" : [ "framework", "zf2" ], 

  "license" : "BSD-3-Clause",

  "homepage" : "http://framework.zend.com/"
   
}`

{
    
"name": "speckcommerce/speck-paypal",
    
"description": "A generic module for adding PayPal support to a ZF2 application.",
    
"type": "library",
    
"keywords": [
       "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://github.com/speckcommerce/SpeckPaypal",
    
"authors": [
        
{
            
"name": "Stephen Rhoades",
            
"email": "steve@stephenrhoades.com",
            
"homepage": "http://www.stephenrhoades.com"
        
}
    
],
    
    "require": {=5.4",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*"
    
},
    
    "autoload": { 
        "psr-0": { 
            "SpeckPaypal": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [ 
            "./"
        ] 
    } 
}

The error message is " [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
"composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
Parse error on line 6:
"keywords" : {
-------------------------^
Expected: 'STRING' - It appears you have an extra trailing comma

I know I am doing something wrong, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: can you post command & error code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some wrong comma:

```
{
   "name" : "zendframework/skeleton-application",
   "description" : "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
   "require" : { 
     "php" : ">=5.4", 
     "zendframework/zendframework" : ">2.2.0rc1", ///<-- delete this comma
   },
   "keywords" : [ "framework", "zf2" ], 
   "license" : "BSD-3-Clause",
   "homepage" : "http://framework.zend.com/" 
}
```

Comment: I fixed that and it seems ok, but when I try to run php composer.phar require speckcommerce/SpeckPaypal it asks for a version constraint, I put 1 because I don't know what version it is (I looked on github) and it said my requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages, Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to it's original content..

Comment: You can try with the latest stable version of zf2 (2.2.5)